# RSpec let method gives nil when used in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec-rails

When I run this test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AssignmentsController do

  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:course) { create(:course) }

  describe "GET 'index'" do
     it "returns http success" do
      assignment = user.assignments.build(name: "Hello 2", start_date: "5/20/2000", due_date: "5/21/2000")
      get :index
      assigns(:assignment).should eq([assignment])
    end
  end
end
```

I get this 
Failure:

```
  1) AssignmentsController GET 'index' returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :index
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `assignments' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/assignments_controller.rb:5:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/assignments_controller_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Why this be since I defined the user variable with lets above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully, you'll see that the error originating from your controller on line 5, not the spec file. Everything should be fine with the let statement the way you have it.

Comment: The controller renders the view find in the browser. Not sure why that cause an error in the tests.

Comment: I'd speculate that you're expecting data to be available in your test environment that isn't there. Hard to say without seeing line 5 of your assignments_controller.rb.

Comment: Maybe you're expecting a course to exist, I notice your let statement is not being used. Remember that these are lazy loaded. If you want a course created before each spec, you can add a `!`, like: `let!(:course) {...}`